# Print sql rows with no fixed columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mysql table called MYTABLE and a sample follows from this table.

```
COL1  COL2  COL3  COL4  COL5   COL6   COL7   COL8   COL9   COL10
25     32    
12     34    22
7
35     10    5     12
2      13    47     3     66
```

Assume that this table has lots of columns and rows but as you see not all column cells are filled.

I use the following code to create a html table with results from this table:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE"; 

$result = mysql_query($query);

$tableresult = "<table>";

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $tableresult .= "<tr><td>" . $row['COL1'] . "</td><td>" . $row['COL2'] . "</td><td>" . $row['COL3'] . "</td></tr>"; 

}

$tableresult .= "</table>"; 
echo $tableresult;
```

First of all, if I want my final printed table in $tableresult to look like the MySQL table is this the right syntax? When I mean right syntax, I mean the same visual format as the SQL table.

And the main issue is that I need to create rows with columns till a column in SQL table has null value.At this example, the creation of the table should stop at COL5 because all rows don't have data after.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you please state an example of the expected result?

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: What do you get when you output that php? A cursory look at it seems like this would give you waht you need. Empty <td>s will just display empty

Comment: What i actually need help with is how to dynamically echo columns. You think that when it finds null to stop printing?

Comment: Do you want all the titles or do you only want the column titles if one column actually has a non null value?

Comment: Exactly the last one! All column cells that have non null content